# upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10

Tags: 16.04, 17.10

I have just downloaded 17.10 and installed it as the upgrade.
The problem that arose, is that I have 33 broken files and not to sure how to fix it.
Also got these two messages:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: Which command did you execute in order to upgrade from 16.04 to 17.10?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: These two messages are about the fact that you are not superuser or root when executing commands which require administrative privileges.

All you need is to first switch user to the root. 
Enter this in your Terminal:

```
sudo su
```

Then enter your root password and then you logged in as root.

After that run the command you want

Second: If your broken files are not personal and related to Ubuntu you can run this command as root for fixing with packet manager:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

**Note**: If you are new to linux do not stay logged in with root. It can cause problems if you make a mistake!